# OpenSSL: genrsa vs genpkey?

Tags: openssl

Why does OpenSSL provide two utilities with so much overlap

`genpkey`:

```
OpenSSL> genpkey -
Usage: genpkey [options]
where options may be
-out file          output file
-outform X         output format (DER or PEM)
-pass arg          output file pass phrase source
-<cipher>          use cipher <cipher> to encrypt the key
-engine e          use engine e, possibly a hardware device.
-paramfile file    parameters file
-algorithm alg     the public key algorithm
-pkeyopt opt:value set the public key algorithm option <opt>
                   to value <value>
-genparam          generate parameters, not key
-text              print the in text
NB: options order may be important!  See the manual page.
```

And `genrsa`:

```
OpenSSL> genrsa -
usage: genrsa [args] [numbits]
 -des            encrypt the generated key with DES in cbc mode
 -des3           encrypt the generated key with DES in ede cbc mode (168 bit key)
 -seed
                 encrypt PEM output with cbc seed
 -aes128, -aes192, -aes256
                 encrypt PEM output with cbc aes
 -camellia128, -camellia192, -camellia256
                 encrypt PEM output with cbc camellia
 -out file       output the key to 'file
 -passout arg    output file pass phrase source
 -f4             use F4 (0x10001) for the E value
 -3              use 3 for the E value
 -engine e       use engine e, possibly a hardware device.
 -rand file:file:...
                 load the file (or the files in the directory) into
                 the random number generator
```

The docs in Debian are also really strange about this,

```
   genpkey   Generation of Private Key or Parameters.
   genrsa    Generation of RSA Private Key. Superceded by genpkey.
```

Is `genpkey` a replacement? If so, how come it doesn't have `-des3`? And, how do we add a password to it, and specify the key length?

Comment: If you think having two different commands to do the same things isn't nuts, then consider that the ASN.1 structure generated `genrsa` and `genpkey` are actually different. The ASN.1 structure of keys generated using `genrsa` is pkcs#1, while keys generated using `genpkey` is pkcs#8. If that's not bad enough, if you use `genpkey -outform der` then it's back to pkcs#1. With EC, it's even worse, somehow `genec` is missing, instead there is `ecparam -genkey`, and somehow `ecparam -genkey`, `genpkey -outform pem`, `genpkey -outform der` all have different ASN.1 structure.

Comment: I wish I could give this comment of yours a bounty or othwise more than just a simple upvote, @LieRyan. It is such an important piece of knowledge that may save one hours of debugging. openSSL is a PITA.

Answer (score 14):

It clearly states that `genrsa` has been superceded by `genpkey`, so yes, `genpkey` is a replacement.

You can change the cipher to `3des` by using the `-cipher` argument

Also, it should tell you that to add a password, you use the `-pass` argument

You can find more information [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/genpkey.html#)

Comment: Well, I do see the `-pass` argument now (assuming that is the same as -3des), but I don't even see an option to specify key length on `genpkey`? I also pasted the entirety of what the Ubuntu 14.04 man pages had to say about it.

Comment: May I point you to this documentation then: [genpkey](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/genpkey.html#)

Comment: Lol, this is nuts... `-pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:numbits`.

Comment: Why is it nuts? :)

Comment: Because the whole purpose of -h is to provide a synopsis of the command. That said, I just found out `genpkey` is actually documented in its own man pages. That's interesting. The whole project should move the direction of git-core, with the man pages all prefixed with openssl-, and the ui permitting `openssl help genpkey` to render the man pages. tldr; better docs would help.